# web.config redirect by ip

Tags: redirect, web-config, ip, security, ip-address

For website security, I would like to redirect a single IP address, or a few IP addresses, to a different domain using web.config. I'm new to this. I know how to limit access or block certain IPs, but is there an easy way to redirect? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To redirect certain IP address you will need to use the [URL redirect rules engine](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) available for IIS 7

Check this link for instructions on how to redirect by IP address:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31509/web-config-to-redirect-except-some-given-ips

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="^123\.123\.123\.123" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="/coming-soon.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks, Victor. Is there a way to do this where it only redirects requests from certain IPs?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reply to Victor's comment, so I'll put my edited code here rather than suggest changes.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="^123\.123\.123\.123" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://www.domain-to-redirect-to/coming-soon.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The change here is that it's redirecting to a new domain as the asker wanted, rather than to a page on the same domain.

Note that if you want to redirect to coming-soon.html on the same domain, you will need to change your match rule, otherwise you will be put into a redirect loop.

Thus:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)coming-soon.html$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="^123\.123\.123\.123" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="/coming-soon.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```